# Possessive of multiple words

Tags: word-usage, possessives

How do you write a possessive of a noun that has a phrase describing it?

Example:

> [The dog at the park]'s food

The food belongs to the dog, not the park. What is the proper way to write something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Dobby the house-elf's former owners"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187807/dobby-the-house-elfs-former-owners)

Answer (score 3):

You don't typically use the apostrophe-**s** possessive for complicated multi-word nouns.

The way you would write it is:

> the food of the dog at the park

or, in this case it would sound better to me as

> the food for the dog at the park

Little kids and people in a hurry who are speaking casually to their friends might say something like

> the-dog-at-the-park-'s food

(sort of by accident), but that construction tends to sound humorous and make us chuckle, even though we do get the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean. You mean *"(The dog at the park)'s food"* :-) This would solve it:

> Food of the dog at the park